# SOLR error java.lang.ClassCastException during indexing

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

Here is my SOLR Data Model,

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "solrData")
public class SolrData {

@Id
@Indexed(name = "id", type = "string")
String id;

@Indexed(name = "name", type = "string")
String name;
```

This SOLR configuration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"com.ows.repository.solrRepository"}, multicoreSupport=true)
@ComponentScan

public class SolrConfig {
    static final String SOLR_HOST = "http://localhost:8983/solr/";

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(SOLR_HOST).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
    }
}
```

The repository,

```
public interface SolrProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrData, String> {
    List<SolrData> findByName(String name);
}
```

The index controller,

```
@Autowired
SolrProductRepository solrProductRepository;

@RequestMapping("/solrindex")
public void solrIndex(Model model) {
        SolrData solrData = new SolrData();
        solrData.setName("You know Who");
        solrProductRepository.save(solrData);
}
```

POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

With the above settings while I go for indexing using the index controller it says,

Updated complete error messages.

```
 org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument cannot be cast to java.util.Map; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.save(SimpleSolrRepository.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.write(MappingSolrConverter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.convertBeanToSolrInputDocument(SolrTemplate.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$4.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate$4.doInSolr(SolrTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:220)
    ... 129 more
```

Comment: can you please add couple of more lines from stacktrace ?

Comment: @Shubhangi, added few lines.

Comment: There seems to be quite a mix up of version in pom.xml. Spring Data Solr 2.1 is not supposed to work with Solr 6.6 plus solr-common in 1.3 does not seem to be reasonable as well. Pls. check your dependencies.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl, you are right. Thank you. With your suggestion and some few tweaks the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem with below settings,

The sole configuration file is changed to below,

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages={"com.ows.rokomari.repository.solrRepository"}, multicoreSupport=true)
@ComponentScan
public class SolrConfig {

static final String SOLR_HOST = "http://localhost:8983/solr";

@Bean
public SolrClient solrClient() {

return new HttpSolrClient(SOLR_HOST);
}

@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
return new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
}
}
```

The pom.xml file is changed to below settings,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now everything is quite fine.

I included solr-common because other than this the project throws error. Since my project is spring and running on version 4 with some other old dependencies. I guess the updated Solr related dependencies conflicts with existing dependencies, which is resolved by this one.

I used spring-data-solr which is bit different from using Solrj. Solrj implemation can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-solrj)